# Font Face issue with Sencha on IE11 on Tomcat Server

Tags: sencha-touch-2, internet-explorer-11, tomcat8, webfonts

We are using Custom web font for our Sencha Touch Application.

We have properly included fonts all formats for all browers.

```
@font-face{
  font-family:"AvenirLight";
  src: url('../fonts/AvenirLTStd-Medium.eot');
  src: url('../fonts/AvenirLTStd-Medium.woff2') format('woff2'),
       url('../fonts/AvenirLTStd-Medium.woff') format('woff'),
       url('../fonts/AvenirLTStd-Medium.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('../fonts/AvenirLTStd-Medium.svg#AvenirLTStd-Medium') format('svg'),
       url('../fonts/AvenirLTStd-Medium.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Also we have defines proper MIME types for these formats in Web xml file

```
 <mime-mapping>
    <extension>eot</extension>
    <mime-type>application/vnd.ms-fontobject</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
<mime-mapping>  
    <extension>otf</extension>  
    <mime-type>application/x-font-opentype</mime-type>  
</mime-mapping>      
<mime-mapping>  
    <extension>ttf</extension>  
    <mime-type>application/x-font-ttf</mime-type>  
</mime-mapping>      
<mime-mapping>  
    <extension>woff</extension>  
    <mime-type>application/x-font-woff</mime-type>  
</mime-mapping>
<mime-mapping>  
    <extension>svg</extension>  
    <mime-type>image/svg+xml</mime-type>  
</mime-mapping>
```

Still we are facing issue in Display of fonts in IE11.

**P.S. - In local we can see correct fonts on Chrome, IE and other browsers.
But when we access from our web server it doesn't shows correct font in IE11**

We are using  Secha 2.4 and Tomcat 8 version.